# How to pass selected list box items and combo values to one table

Tags: ms-access

I have a form with combo box 1 and 2, I also have a list box on the form.
I want to be be able to put the values from the comboboxes and the selected items into new rows for each item selected in the list box (duplicate the combo values). Thank you!

```vb
Private Sub Command222_Click()

 ''ADD STUDENTS INTO COHORT TABLE
    On Error GoTo Err:

    Const KEY_VIOLATION = 3022
    Dim ctrl As Control
    Dim strSQL  As String
    Dim strSQL2 As String
    Dim varItem As Variant
    Dim x As Integer


    Set ctrl = Me.lstFirst
     
    If ctrl.ItemsSelected.Count > 0 Then
        For Each varItem In ctrl.ItemsSelected
        
            strSQL = "INSERT INTO tbl_cohorts(studentID,StudentFirstName,StudentLastName) " & _
                "SELECT StudentID,StudentFirstName,StudentLastName, txt_cohortID" & _
                "FROM tbl_students " & _
                "WHERE StudentID = " & ctrl.ItemData(varItem)
                
            CurrentDb.Execute strSQL, dbFailOnError
        Next varItem

        For x = 0 To Me.lstSecond.ListCount - 1
            Me.lstSecond.Selected(x) = True
        Next x
                   
    End If

    strSQL2 = "DELETE * FROM tbl_NamesSelected"
    CurrentDb.Execute strSQL2, dbFailOnError
    Me.lstSecond.Requery

    Exit Sub

Err:
    Select Case Err.Number
        Case KEY_VIOLATION
        Resume Next
        Case Else
        MsgBox Err.Description, vbExclamation, "Error"
    End Select

End Sub
```

Comment: And your question or issue is ..?

Comment: What fields should the comboboxes and list values go into? If the data you want to save is in comboboxes and list box, why pull data from tbl_students? Why are you duplicating student name into tbl_cohorts? Should save only studentID.